# Is there a way to pull null values as None from SQL table into pandas DataFrame table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am using pd.read_sql() to pull data from sql server into jupyter workbook for processing

```
 A             B     Value                   C        D        E           F    
Electricity cfcrow1  NaN                RCFCELEC1   CFC2    IndType1    20112012
Electricity cfcrow3  None               RCFCELEC1   CFC2    IndType1    20112012
```

in both the cases the value column had NULL in the actual database but it fetched one as NaN and the other as None. It would be better if both were **None**.

Comment: What's the data type of the `Value` column? If it's a char- or nchar-based column are you sure one of them wasn't actually `'null'` instead of `null`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am confident they are null and if they were 'null' it will actually retrieve null as a text I think

Comment: `SELECT cast(null as decimal), cast(null as float), cast(null as int), cast(null as nvarchar(5)), cast(null as varchar(5))` in a Python 3 Jupyter notebook returns `0  None  None  None  None  None` so, again, I ask: what's the data type of the `Value` column? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69299008/edit) your question to show the code you were trying to execute.